# Use Central Limit Theorem to determine distribution

Tags: distributions, random-variable, central-limit-theorem

## Task

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be a sequence of independent random variables with standard uniform distribution $U(0, 1)$.

Lets define $Y_1 = X_1$ and
$$
Y_i = \begin{cases} X_i & i \mbox{ is even} \\ 1 - X_{i-1} & i \mbox{ is odd, } i > 2 \end{cases}
$$
$$
W_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i \qquad n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
$$
B_n = \frac{W_n - \mathbb{E}(W_n)}{\sqrt{Var(W_n)}}
$$

I need to figure out the distribution of the $B_n$ (as $n \to \infty$) using CLT.

## My attempt

$$
W_n = \begin{cases} X_1 + \frac{n - 2}{2} + X_n & n \mbox{ is even} \\ X_1 + \frac{n-1}{2} & n \mbox{ is odd}\end{cases}
$$
But I don't know how to determine the distribution of $B_n$ using it.

Comment: I don't think CLT applies here...

Comment: $B_n$ is uniformly distributed between $-\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ if $n$ is odd, and has a symmetrical triangular distribution between $-\sqrt{6}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ if $n$ is even. No matter how large $n$ is, there will be no convergence to normality.